# find in /sys/class does not show everything, why?

Tags: filesystems, find

Like every other person I am from time to time compelled to list the directory structure from a certain point int the filesystem. I do so with `find /path/in/fs/` and this yields something like:

```
/path/in/fs/subfolder1
/path/in/fs/subfolder1/file1
/path/in/fs/subfolder1/subfolder2/yetanothefile
/path/in/fs/subfolder1/subfolder2/yetanothefile2
/path/in/fs/subfolder1/subfolder2/yetanothefile3
/path/in/fs/subfolder1/file2
```

in a way this saves me from endless iterations of `cd` and `ls`.

Now I wanted to list the directory structure in the `/sys/class` path and I think it falls short. The next two commands show the odd behavior:

- (1) using the `cd` and `ls`

```
    root@freak:/sys/class/hwmon# ls
    hwmon0  hwmon1  hwmon2
    root@freak:/sys/class/hwmon# cd hwmon0
    root@freak:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0# ls
    name  power  subsystem  temp1_crit  temp1_input  uevent
```

- (2) using the said `find` command at the same place

```
    root@freak:/sys/class/hwmon# find .
    .
    ./hwmon0
    ./hwmon1
    ./hwmon2
```

As you can see it seems to me that `find` does not show me everything, which I find an odd and suprising behavior. 
Now I know that stuff below /sys/ is somehow special. Still it all works the `cd` `ls` way. Somebody has an answer why this happens and better even how I can make find not overlook the content in ./hwmon0 ./hwmon1 ... etc for instance?

Comment: `hwmon0`, `hwmon1`, and `hwmon2` are probably symlinks. The actual location of those directories is elsewhere in the `/sys` hierarchy.

Comment: yip. thank you. how could I overlook that..  thank you.

Comment: since I mindelessly overlooked to check if it is symbolic links I cast my `find` on I have not received the result. A solution hence was to use `find /sys/class/hwmon -follow -maxdepth 3`

Comment: if you want find all files in the same just use `find /sys/class/  -type f`

Comment: @humanityANDpeace  just update your post , what you want in output ? and what you want to achieve...

Comment: @RahulPatil Pardon me, but I think the question is both solved -by the comment from Celeda (which as an answer I would have accepted)- amd -explained I wanted to know what causes find not to show everything in the directory which `ls` would... (the reason was **symbolic links**) I appreciate your input Rahul, but I am really uncertain there is really something I can still improve. Maybe Celade will be good enought to write his assumption for the "suspected missbehaviour" as an answer I can except? well, Rahul pls give me feedback

Comment: @humanityANDpeace Please check my answer , if you still have any doubts , just let me know..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run

```
find .
```

then it will take `-P` by default Option , it is actually run `find -P .`

Extracted From `man find`

```
   -P     Never follow symbolic links.  This  is  the  default  behaviour.
      When find examines or prints information a file, and the file is
      a symbolic link, the information used shall be  taken  from  the
      properties of the symbolic link itself.
```

that's why find does not show you everything under `/sys/class/hwmon`, if you go inside and check it's all symbolic link, So you just need to check using `find . -follow`

For more information check `man find`

Comment: yes indeed, as already laid out in the comments by Celada and myself **symbolic links** have been the reason. Though not personally of additional use your answer can be of value for all the people who will hence have a Question and an Answer. I will accept it surely. Thank you!

Comment: -follow is deprecated. Use the '-L' option instead: `find -L`. PS: If the path is '.' then you can omit it.